# Скачивается jsp страница вместо открытия её в браузере

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, jsp, page

Проблема в том, что при открытии страницы открывается проводник для её скачивания, проблема появилась неожиданно и откат на прежнюю точку не помог
web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/config/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/config/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

mvc-config.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="project.controller"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/il8n/messages"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false"/>
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/*"/>
            <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="locale"/> <!--?locale=en для смены локали-->
            </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Сама страница которая раньше открывалась и в IDE всё, что в атрибуте style стало серым и идея это не воспринимает

    Login page

```
<style>
    .form-width {max-width: 25rem;}
    .has-float-label {
        position: relative; }
    .has-float-label label {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        cursor: name;
        font-size: 75%;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all .2s;
        transition: all .2s;
        top: -.5em;
        left: 0.75rem;
        z-index: 3;
        line-height: 1;
        padding: 0 1px; }
    .has-float-label label::after {
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: white;
        height: 2px;
        top: 50%;
        left: -.2em;
        right: -.2em;
        z-index: -1; }
    .has-float-label .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all .2s;
        transition: all .2s; }
    .has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        opacity: 0; }
    .has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus) + label {
        font-size: 150%;
        opacity: .5;
        top: .3em; }

    .input-group .has-float-label {
        display: table-cell; }
    .input-group .has-float-label .form-control {
        border-radius: 0.25rem; }
    .input-group .has-float-label:not(:last-child) .form-control {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0; }
    .input-group .has-float-label:not(:first-child) .form-control {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        margin-left: -1px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="p-x-1 p-y-3">
        <form method="post" action="<c:url value="/login"/>" class="card card-block m-x-auto bg-faded form-width">
            <legend class="m-b-1 name-xs-center">Login in</legend>
            <span>${message}</span>
            <div class="form-group has-float-label">
                <input id="login" name="login" type="name" placeholder="Login" class="form-control"/>
                <label for="login">Login</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-float-label">
                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div>
            <span>${error}</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            <div class="name-xs-center">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Log In</button>
            </div>
            <h4 class="name-center"><a href="<c:url value="/registration"/>">Create new account</a></h4>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Может, не хватает заголовка?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець всё есть, просто на стал полную страницу выкладывать

Comment: Попробуйте указать для `class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"` `id="jspViewResolver"`

Comment: @SpringNewbie не помогло